# SQL : Join after Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Ive got a big SQL statement.

But i want to test the where clause on the firsttable (T1) and after that, make all the joins on the rows selected using the where clause.

Because actually the query is very slow, cause MySQL join all the tables to t1 and then test the where clause !

```
SELECT * from FIRSTTABLE T1
        LEFT JOIN T2 on (....)
        LEFT JOIN T3 on (....)
WHERE T1.column = '1' OR T1.column= '5'
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Use `explain` to find out where you need an index

Comment: In a query optimization question, you should include the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename> for each table in the query. Help us help you -- don't make us guess at which indexes and data types you currently have. Also include the EXPLAIN for the current query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT * from 
(
SELECT * from FIRSTTABLE T1
WHERE T1.column = '1' OR T1.column= '5'
) as T2 

LEFT JOIN T3 on (....)
LEFT JOIN T4 on (....)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

SQL queries are *compiled* and *optimized* before they are executed.  The order of clauses in a query really has nothing to do with the final execution plan.  More specifically, the filtering conditions in the `WHERE` clause could take place before, after, or even during the `JOIN` processing.

You can start to learn about SQL optimization by understanding indexes.  The MySQL documentation is a very reasonable place to start.

Comment: There's no trick even if the where statement just filter the original table and not the joined table ?

Comment: @Anthony . . . The optimizer is deciding how the query is run, based on statistics on the data and available indexes.

Comment: (180 characters left)